Laravel hosting googiehost .htaccess problem
I am using googiehost shared hosting for free laravel hosting. And I am completely new to hosting laravel projects. I placed all of my laravel project files into public_html folder. I accidently deleted all existing files before I upload my files into that. I tried several .htaccess codes but none of that worked. Sometimes, it's 403 Forbidden and other routes are 404 not found. Some codes doesn't even work like unable to handle this request. What should I do? PHP version is 8.2 with laravel 10
Current .htaccess is
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

And it's showing 403 forbidden in root url.
My website url is
https://hoyomm-wiki.c1.is/
I've already imported tables and everything. Please help me!

Probably best off starting afresh. Create another goggiehost account and copy the files from there if you have to.
